# Bootstrap not showing css after AJAX xmlhttp.responseText

Tags: jquery, ajax

hi i have the code below which loads to the page a dropdown menu when a selection from another dropdown is selected.

```
<script>
function showGroup(str) {
    if (str == "") {
        document.getElementById("groupselect").innerHTML = "";
        return;
    } else { 
        if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {
            // code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
            xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
        } else {
            // code for IE6, IE5
            xmlhttp = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
        }
        xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
            if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status == 200) {
                document.getElementById("groupselect").innerHTML = xmlhttp.responseText;
            }
        }
        xmlhttp.open("GET","groups.php?q="+str,true);
        xmlhttp.send();
    }
}
</script>
```

and in the file groups.php i have this code

```
<div class='form-group' >   
            <label>Groups:</label>
            <select id='group' name='groups[]' multiple='multiple'>



            <option value='agis'>agis</option>
            <option value='idas'>idas</option>
            <option value='alkap'>alkap</option>
            <option value='dkan'>dkan</option>

            </select>

            <script src="js/jquery.multiple.select.js"></script>                

            <script>
            $("#group").multipleSelect();
            </script>
```

and when it returns the css and all the jquery not working.
If i run groups.php alone it works perfectly.
Can someone help with that??
Thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

You probably need to build the dropdown menu after the AJAX call. So try something this:

```
if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status == 200) {
    document.getElementById("groupselect").innerHTML = xmlhttp.responseText;
    $("#group").multipleSelect();
}
```

Remove the scripts from `groups.php` and put `jquery.multiple.select.js` in your AJAX page.

Comment: I tried to put the scripts in my ajax page but still the same